# How can I attach python code(backend) with C# code(frontend)?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

I'm building a human behavior prediction software for which I have implemented deep learning methods in python, I have designed the front end in unity3D using C# in which it simulate the behavior of human. Now the issue is I want to attach the code written in python with my front end which is in unity3D. How can I do that, is there any "dll" file of python which I can attach with C# or is there any other solution?

I have tried surfing on google but haven't find any solid guidance regarding the problem as of now. I have read that we can use ".dll" file but still I have no idea of how to do that.

I expect my back end code which in python attached with front end code which is in C#. Front end is basically designed in Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

You can embed python code into C#/.net with IronPython.net. This is the route I would go if you are seeking an in-process solution where the frontend and backend all run in the same application on the same computer. Create a C# project with Visual Studio and wire up UI events to function calls into IronPython.

I will add an example when I get a chance.